# How can I use a variable from another jframe?

Tags: java, swing

I have a jframe (`DuasPaginas2`) that opens when I click the "next" button that is in another jframe (`DuasPaginas`), and in the second jFrame (`DuasPaginas2`)  I have a comboBox (`cbx3`) that conforms to the option I Choose Place a value in a text field (`txtValor`) and then have another text field in a user name and enter a value (`txtValue1`).

And my question is this: having a button on the first jframe (`DuasPaginas`) that allows me to do an add operation and then presents me the value in jlabel (`jLabelResultado`), how do I use the variables (`txtValor` and `txtValor1`) introduced In the second jframe (`DuasPaginas2`) to do the sum with the button in the first jFrame?

If possible help me with examples because my knowledge in java is not very advanced.

Second jFrame (`DuasPaginas2`)

```
private void cbx3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    int resultado = 0;

    String i = cbx3.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if(i.equals("baixo"))resultado=1;
    else if(i.equals("medio"))resultado=2;
    else if(i.equals("alto"))resultado=3;

    txtValor.setText(String.valueOf(resultado));
}
```

Jframe `DuasPaginas`

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        DuasPaginas2 obj = new DuasPaginas2();
        obj.setVisible(true);            
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        int valorUm=0;
        int valorDois=0;
        int valorFinal=0;
        valorUm = Integer.parseInt(txtValor1.getText());
        valorDois = Integer.parseInt(txtValor.getText());

        valorFinal=valorUm+valorDois;
        jLabel1.setText(valorFinal+"");
    }
```

The button to do the sum operation on the first jframe.
Give me error on this part.

Comment: Please post a bit more of code, the fragment you posted is not enough to understand your issue. Need more context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communication between two different JFrames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127140/communication-between-two-different-jframes)

Comment: Look now, i edit a little more, and Try to explain me with an example if it can be. thanks

Comment: @JoãoMarques, AxelH was right - this is a dublicate. You can pass your first frame, controls or texts as a constructor parameter.